# multiple forms with ajax/jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I am using this plugin: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started

I am having issues, getting it to submit (using a single function) more than one form on the page at the same time, and to make it more complicated, I am loading the form via ajax from a remote html call. So the form function needs to be loaded again.

The question is how to use (if possible) a re-usable function that can submit multiple forms at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can use [LiveQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) Plugin for that problem. It could work like for example

```
<button ... rel="formId"/>
jQuery(".formButton").livequery("click",function() {
  var formId=jQuery(this).attr("rel");
  jQuery("#"+formId).ajaxSubmit();
}
```

So button with class .formButton can be included in server response and with livequery it is also be handled.
Hope it helps.
Sorry for my English.

Comment: Note for anyone reading this answer ... jQuery now has a $.live() function that binds an event listener to dynamic DOM nodes.  No need for a plugin to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery plugin add an event listener to the onsubmit event of the form(s) you specify. So in order to submit multiple forms at the same time you'll need a function that invokes the submit events of each form. Something like this:

```
function doubleSubmit(e) {
 if (e.target.id == 'form2') {
   $('#form1').submit();
  } else {
   $('#form2').submit();
  }
}
```

The next trick is to have this function be called when either form submits. I would do something like this:

```
$("#form1").bind("submit", doubleSubmit);
$("#form2").bind("submit", doubleSubmit);
```

I haven't tested this code, but it should give you the general idea.

Comment: I'm not convinced this will work. Won't this just submit 'the other' form, since one postback will occur, cancelling the other?

Answer (score 0):

You can't submit multiple forms at once.  But you could submit them sequentially

```
function submitFn() {
$('form').each(function() {
$.post(url, data, function() {
... 

 }
return false;
});}
```

and add listeners:

```
$('form').bind('submit', submitFn);
```

The return false is important coz if you don't have it then the first form submitted will submit twice

Answer (score 0):

Id probably go for something like this:

```
// after you import the html
$("#form1, #form2").bind("submit", submit);
// or simply
$("form").bind("submit", submit);

function submit() {
  /// a $.post implementation selecting all the controls and passing them as data
  return false; // to prevent an actual browser submit
}
```